# Determine location of Hive UDF

Tags: hive

Is there a way to locate the hdfs/local path of a particular UDF's jar/class file?

When I run "show functions" I am able to see this UDF but I want to find out it's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive has two types of functions permanent/Built-in and temporary.
**Permenent:** Built-in functions are part of [hive-exec**.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec/2.1.0) under package "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf". Jar is under HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-exec*.jar.

**Temporary:** functions are added manually. in case of temporary function you will find details in your hive hql file. e.g.

```
ADD JAR xyz.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION temp AS 'com.example.hive.udf.Temp';
```

Hive of [0.13+](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6047) UDF can also be added permanently using [plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins).

Find out details about hive function:

```
DESCRIBE FUNCTION EXTENDED function_name;
DESCRIBE FUNCTION function_name;
```